# Built a RoR app previously with Ruby 1.9.3, if I use a new computer and install Ruby 2.1.2 will that cause problems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9.3, ruby-2.1

I have an RoR app built previously with Ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.0.1. I have deployed to Heroku previously with this setup. If I would like to use Ruby 2.1.2 on my new computer, when accessing the app code and trying to deploy again on Heroku will my app encounter problems because of the different Ruby versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this compatibility matrix](http://www.devalot.com/articles/2012/03/ror-compatibility), you will need a Ruby version 2.x.

```
Rails Version    Possible Ruby Versions  Recommended Ruby Version
1.0–2.1          1.8.6                   1.8.6
2.2              1.8.6 or 1.8.7          1.8.7
2.3              1.8.6, 1.8.7, or 1.9.1  1.8.7
3.0–3.2          1.8.7, 1.9.2, or 1.9.3  1.9.3
4.0–…            1.9.3, 2.0.x            2.0.x
```

Comment: hi, thank you for the compatibility matrix, do you mean rails 4x for using ruby 2.0.x?

Comment: Yes.  [This page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) also states you need Rails 4.x with Ruby 2.x